# How to get initialValues for a reduxFrom from state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using my forms with react redux. I have the same form for editing and creating a new one.

I want, when opening my form, that, if editing, I put the initial values of the form, from my api.

I have already tried the official documentation, but its not working.

This is my Form:

```
class Form extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    const tripId = this.props.match.params.uid;
    if(tripId){
      this.fetchData(tripId);
    }
  }

  fetchData = async (tripId) => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'token';
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/vnd.trips.v1+json';
    await axios.get(`myurl`) 
    .then(res => {
      const trip = res.data;
      this.setState({ 
        trip: trip,
        isLoading: false,
        initialValues: trip
      });
    })
    console.log('Terminou de carregar')
  }

(....)
Form = reduxForm({ form: 'trip', enableReinitialize : true })(Form)
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { intl, vehicleTypes, users, dialogs, trip } = state

  return {
    intl,
    vehicleTypes,
    users,
    dialogs,
    initialValues: trip
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, { setDialogIsOpen }
)(injectIntl(withRouter(withTheme()(Form))))
```

But my initialValues are never filled, and comes always blank. I debuged the code, and I see that my API is loading and setting the state on my fetchData method. So, what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're trying to pass `initialValues` through `this.setState` which is not going to work, reduxForm expect `initialValues` to be passed as `props`.

One thing to mention, there is a difference between the `application state` and `component local state`, first one -application state- is clearly managed by redux, and the other one -local component state- is managed by react which you can modify by calling `this.setState`

so to fix this, you should be dispatching an action when you receive the data from your api, and you update your props in `mapStateToProps`

your code should look like:

```
class Form extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    const tripId = this.props.match.params.uid;
    if(tripId){
      this.fetchData(tripId);
    }
  }

  fetchData = async (tripId) => {
    await axios.get(`https://toptal-backend-fmaymone.c9users.io/trips/${tripId}`) 
    .then(res => {
      const trip = res.data;
      this.props.fillTheForm(trip);
    })
    console.log('Terminou de carregar')
  }

(....)
Form = reduxForm({ form: 'trip', enableReinitialize : true })(Form)
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { intl, vehicleTypes, users, dialogs, trip } = state

  return {
    intl,
    vehicleTypes,
    users,
    dialogs,
    initialValues: trip
  }
}

const fillTheForm = (dispatch) => (trip) => {
  // here you dispatch the action and update your application state
  // in your reducer when this action is dispatched,
  // then mapStateToProps should be called and the data you just
  // passed in your reducer should be in (state)
  dispatch()
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, { setDialogIsOpen, fillTheForm }
)(injectIntl(withRouter(withTheme()(Form))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @d7my . But I still dont understand how to set the state inside the fillTheForm method. Because I cant add a this.setState{initialValues: dispatch} (because of course the "this" is not acessible inside the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

As @d7my said, your mistake is that you are trying to change a `prop` through the `setState`, they are different things in react world. The fastest way to fix your problem, it would be replacing that:

```
this.setState({
   trip: trip,
   isLoading: false,
   initialValues: trip
});
```

For:

```
this.props.initialize(trip)
```

The prop `initialize` is exported by redux-form to your component to update the form initial state. I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5y80vz3q) where you can check it working.

Said that, I believe you should change the structure of your component, instead of loading your data inside the component (componentDidMount), you should do it inside a redux action and then update your state. Doing this way, you could easily get the form data from your redux state on `mapStateToProps` function and set `initialValues` prop instead of use `initialize` props, that is much better.